# What is the best solution for type definition management system(like tsd) for Typescript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, tsd

When it comes to use Typescript, we need to consider how to resolve type definition files (*.d.ts).

As long as I know, there are several systems for managing typescript definition system as below.

- tsd
- typings
- @types

I guess tsd is the oldest one and that is origin.
But, why `typings`needed to be born? I guess making definition file for typings is a little bit complex.

And what is `@types` actually?

Then, what is the best solution around this?

Comment: I just manually manage my typings locally; works wonder. I occasionaly copy them from definatelyTyped if they're of good enough quality and up to date, which is not that often.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The story behind the typings management ecosystem around TypeScript is very big.

First there was ( still is ) a monolith repository called [DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped) which was used as a hub to all developers that wanted to contribute their typings for different libraries.

Because of this repository a typings manager called `tsd` which directly takes the typings from that repository and saves them locally in your project.

Meanwhile the DT repo exceeded it's scaling abilities and [had to be restructured](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues?q=is%3Aopen+is%3Aissue+label%3ADiscussion). The discussion went further in the way how a `d.ts.` file should look like, so at one point there was a need for another way of including the typings in your project. Another problem was the versioning of libraries and TypeScript compiler itself.

Then at one point [Blake Embrey](https://github.com/blakeembrey) created a new typings manager called `typings` which had a support for `DefinitelyTyped` and the new proposed way of structuring a `d.ts`. The new structure allowed for two types of modules - globals ( most of the DefinitelyTyped ones ) and modules that are supposed to be encapsulated.

Later [TypeScript 2.0 Beta](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2016/07/11/announcing-typescript-2-0-beta/) was announced by Microsoft. The team behind TypeScript realized the need of a different way in handling typing files. What they did was a `@types` npm scope, which [they announced will be the new way of handling typings](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2016/06/15/the-future-of-declaration-files/). At this point `@types` only works with TypeScript 2.0.

> Declaration files (.d.ts files) are a fundamental part of using existing JavaScript libraries in TypeScript, but getting them has always been a place where we’ve known there was room for improvement. As we get closer to TypeScript 2.0, we’re very excited to show off a sneak peak of our plan to simplify things. Getting type declarations in TypeScript 2.0 will require no tools apart from npm.

So to the answer of your question :

**If you use TypeScript below v2.0 use `typings`, but if you use 2.0 use `@types`**

Comment: Thanks @drinchev, looks accurate - something worth pointing out is that Typings was and is an exercise to show how dependencies _should_ be managed using TypeScript (previously it wasn't possible with DefinitelyTyped + TSD, and as a module author myself this was unacceptable). TypeScript now understands this and has worked to help incorporate a proposal into core for 2.0.